# Is it possible to export HTML along with SVG markup to the Highcharts Export Server (http://export.highcharts.com/)

Tags: svg, highcharts, jsplumb

I have a case where my page displays HTML along with SVG markup together. Its an JSPlumb(http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/home/dom.html) demo.
  I need to export this data/design to a PDF or a PNG file. Can this be done using the Highcharts export library or is there any other library which can solve my requirement?

Comment: As I can see in DOM, JSPlumb is using DIV elements to generate endPoints. Highcharts exporting server is working only for SVG.

Answer (score 1):

[PhantomJs to the rescue](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html).

This script:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 1000, height: 600 };
page.open('http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demo/flowchart/dom.html', function() {
  page.render('jsPlumb.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Produces this png:

[image]

Comment: Is this a web based solution. The JsPlumb tool which i am making will run in a browser and will have an export button. Will PhantomJS meet this requirement.

Comment: @Brian_Noronha, no, PhantomJS is a command line tool.  You'd have to wrap it into a web service that you could call into. If you google a bit there lots of people already doing it.  Phantom even has some limited built-in support to run itself as a webserver: http://benjaminbenben.com/2013/07/28/phantomjs-webserver/.